# Examples for a modern home screen in a Windows desktop application?

Tags: gui-design, menu, desktop-application, refresh

I have a 15 year old Windows desktop application, and I'd like to refresh the look of it to be more modern, in line with current trends in UI design.
The main functions are launched from a home screen within the application (this is the application's own desktop). Currently each function is represented by an icon.

For the past few years I've seen that many such applications adopted the metro UI with live tiles. But for Windows 11, Microsoft seems to have dropped these tiles even from the Start menu, so I suppose that's not the direction they'll be going in the future.

Can you point me (preferably with links and/or screenshots) to existing desktop application home screen designs that are modern/progressive and in line with latest UI design trends?

Comment: Hi and welcome to UX.SE! If you want to see latest UI design trends, check out Behance or Dribbble and search "ui design" on them. Beware though that a lot of them are considered "glamour" shots (because those two sites are often used for designer portfolios – aka jobseeking) and might not be implementable in any real way.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots of your software?